# In Genesis 32 what is the significance of Jacob's injury?

Tags: genesis

In some kind of divine encounter Jacob receives a hip injury:

> NIV Genesis 32: 
>   22During the night Jacob got up and took his two
>   wives, his two servant wives, and his eleven sons and crossed the
>   Jabbok River with them. 23After taking them to the other side, he sent
>   over all his possessions. 24This left Jacob all alone in the camp, and
>   a man came and wrestled with him until the dawn began to break. 25 **When
>   the man saw that he would not win the match, he touched Jacob’s hip
>   and wrenched it out of its socket**. 26Then the man said, “Let me go,
>   for the dawn is breaking!”
>
> But Jacob said, “I will not let you go unless you bless me.”
>
> 27“What is your name?” the man asked.
>
> He replied, “Jacob.”
>
> 28“Your name will no longer be Jacob,” the man told him. “From now on
>   you will be called Israel, because you have fought with God and with
>   men and have won.”
>
> 29“Please tell me your name,” Jacob said.
>
> “Why do you want to know my name?” the man replied. Then he blessed
>   Jacob there.
>
> 30Jacob named the place Peniel (which means “face of God”), for he
>   said, “I have seen God face to face, yet my life has been spared.”
>   31The sun was rising as Jacob left Peniel, and **he was limping because
>   of the injury to his hip. 32(Even today the people of Israel don’t eat
>   the tendon near the hip socket because of what happened that night
>   when the man strained the tendon of Jacob’s hip.)**

How is this significant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may have been God's way of preventing Jacob from fathering more than twelve sons.

- [Here is the extract from a 1997 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9062949#) into the injury Jacob suffered.

> This study describes in modern medical terms a traumatic hip injury suffered by the Biblical patriarch Jacob approximately 3,500 years ago ... He appears to have sustained neurological injury to his sciatic nerve as well as musculoskeletal damage to his hip.

- [Here is an article on sexual dysfunction](http://www.sciatica-pain.org/sciatica-sexual-dysfunction.html) associated with sciatica.

> The structural contributor to sciatica-related sexual dysfunction usually revolves around nerve compression of the cauda equina nerve roots in the central canal, due to spinal stenosis.  This process can cause sciatica, but can also affect the viability of the lower sacral nerves, before they exit through their designated neuroforamen.  These nerves are responsible for providing many of the anatomical changes associated with sexual response.

- [Here is a Wikipedia article about *Gid hanasheh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gid_hanasheh), the name the Jews give to the tendon associated with Jacob's injury.

> Gid hanasheh (Hebrew: גִּיד הַנָּשֶׁה‎‎), often translated as "displaced tendon," is the term for sciatic nerve in Judaism. It may not be eaten by Jews according to Halacha (Jewish Law). The laws of prohibition regarding the gid hanasheh are found in Tractate Chullin (Hullin), chapter 7.

- [Here is an article proffering a reason for the concern](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/784896/jewish/Why-dont-we-eat-the-sciatic-nerve.htm) Jews have about *Gid hanasheh*.

> The Zohar teaches us that in every struggle we are powerful, and can overcome our evil urges if we so desire. There is only one place where the lust is so strong that even great men are powerless—the gid hanasheh.

Comment: While I have accepted this answer it is odd that God chose to go about it in a way with such a significant side effect.

Comment: I doubt  this is the full answer, but this is a really good point. +1

Comment: Exactly. It answers the question and then raises another question!

Answer (score 1):

~ In part it could be that the Man with whom Jacob was wrestling with was revealing himself to be no ordinary man. It could also be that the Man simply tried to bring the match to a close. However, Jacob was so tenacious that he refused to stop wrestling.

Subsequent to this Jacob may have limped for a few days and then recovered.

*Note I also want to add that this takes place in ch. 32 and 3 chapters later, Jacob goes on to have a son. Benjamin is born.

Comment: Good point about him having a son after this, (unless it is within nine months, which I didn't check).

Answer (score 0):

Further possibilities - 1) related to his heal-grabbing name.  2) being nomadic and self-confident, Jacob would now have to depend on God to get around.

Comment: Hi BigQ and welcome to the site. Normally your answer would be disqualified on the grounds of being too brief and unsupported but they are interesting to consider and you being a newbie I gave you thumbs up. Please, though, take the tour of the site here if you hope to not experience a lot of painful rejection!  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

**In Genesis 32 what is the significance of Jacob's injury?**

Perhaps to teach him humility; a constant reminder not to be overly exalted because of his God-given prosperity or for having grappled with an angel.

That was something to keep him lowly, to show that this victory was not in his own strength and that the angel had superior power.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob's injury, specifically regarding the sciatica nerve, have annual observed fast days references.

The words the sciatica nerve in Hebrew represents the observed fast days of the year as follows:

לֹֽא־יֹאכְל֨וּ בְנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֜ל אֶת־גִּ֣יד הַנָּשֶׁ֗ה
All the fast days (when we don't eat) are in the words אֶת־גִּ֣יד הַנָּשֶׁ֗ה:

גִּ֣: tzum gedaliah
י:and Asarah bTeves
Yom Kippur
תאֶ: Taanis Esther and
Tisha (b)Av
יד: Taanis Bchoros
גִּ֣יד: Shiva Asar Btamuz
הַנָּשֶׁ֗ה-השֶׁ֗נָּהַ: throughout each year

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).